# How i can add a new contact to phone contacts using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, vcf-vcard

I am new to flutter and my college project require to save VCF file to contacts.

So i am trying to find a way to import my VCF file into my phone contacts.
I used vcard_maintained https://pub.dev/packages/vcard_maintained to create the vcf file.
can please tell me how i can lauch the phone contact from my flutter app and pass the data to it.

The Function that create the VCF:

```
 save: () {
                      var vCard = VCard();
                      vCard.firstName = testingdatalist[index].displayname!;
                      vCard.jobTitle = testingdatalist[index].jobtitle!;
                      vCard.workPhone = testingdatalist[index].phonenumber1!;
                      vCard.note = testingdatalist[index].about!;
                      vCard.email = testingdatalist[index].email!;
                      vCard.saveToFile('./contact.vcf');
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flutter_contacts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts) package. you can simply create a `Contact` object from `.vcf` file content and insert it!

```
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

// Import contact from vCard
Contact contact = Contact.fromVCard('BEGIN:VCARD\n'
      'VERSION:3.0\n'
      'N:;Joe;;;\n'
      'TEL;TYPE=HOME:123456\n'
      'END:VCARD');

contact.insert();
```

p.s: in order to create contacts you need to add READ and WRITE permissions to your application. for that, Add the following key/value pair to your app's Info.plist (for iOS):

```
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
     ...
     <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
     <string>Reason we need access to the contact list</string>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

Add the following  tags to your app's AndroidManifest.xml (for Android):

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
     <application ...>
     ...
```